# Angular Micro front end

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a micro front end application with Angular 8. I am not able to find any support in Angular official site. Can some one please tell weather  this approach is mature enough for implementing actual projects. Is there any application available in public domain which is built with micro front end approach in Angular 8? What are the security and performance parameters we need to consider before or after building micro front end app.

Comment: Micro front-end is an architectural style to avoid the limitations of large, monolithic front-ends, very similar to micro-services in back-end. It is more than just a frame-work. You may want to use monorepo with independently deployable small packages using lerna or nx tools. I don't think Angular can provide this out of the box currently.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to build a micro front end application with Angular 8

wow, thats great..go ahead. Gud Luck !!.

> I am not able to find any support in Angular official site

Angular has been equipped you with *@angular/elements* 2 year back (2016-2017). Now make any plain old angular component (*POAC*) as a web component and use anywhere in the world of javascripts based framework(React,Vue,Electron etc).

> Can some one please tell weather this approach is mature enough for implementing actual projects

Anyone can tell about this, it is just architecture of your system (ur application) and it is cool , Monolith is pain, micro front end is remedy for this pain.

> Is there any application available in public domain which is built with micro front end approach in Angular 8?

YES, Many and Many in near future and it is not about in angular or any other framework, its plateform/framework independent and that is beauty of it.

> What are the security and performance parameters we need to consider before or after building micro front end app.

Keep in mind - Micro-frontends are split by business domain, not by location on the page

Answer (score 0):

Step wise procedure to create micro front end using module federation in angular 13.

Install nx globally

1. npm i –g nx
2. npm install –g @nrwl/cli
3. npm install –g angular/cli@Version

**Create empty nx workspace-**

```
npx create-nx-workspace ng-mfe
```

Note:- While creating workspace if cypress is not downloading then set proxy using following command
•   set HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com

**Add Angular package**

```
npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular
```

**Create host angular application**

```
npx nx g @nrwl/angular:app dashboard --mfe --mfeType=host --routing=true
```

**Create remote application, set hostname and mfeType as remote**

```
npx nx g @nrwl/angular:app login --mfe --mfeType=remote --port=4201 --host=dashboard --routing=true
```

**To run all applications there is command is shell – project.json file**

```
  nx serve-mfe [hostName]
```

**Configuration settings**

**1.common styles configurations.**

Create new folder under libs which will hold scss files. Add path for external stylesheet in every applications style.scss file
Import this scss file using following syntax
for Ex.

```
@import '../../../libs/sass-style/common.scss';
```

**2.service configuration.**

create a user data-access library that we will share between the host application and the remote application.
Create data-access-user folder in lib

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:lib shared/data-access-user
```

Create service under data-access-user folder’s shared lib

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:service user --project=shared-data-access-user
```

Add a new export to the shared/data-access-user's index.ts file:

```
export * from './lib/user.service';
```

Import shared services using following syntax
Ex.

```
 import { UserService } from '@[main workspace name]/shared/data-access-user'
```

**3.Assets configuration.**

Create new folder under libs which will hold another folder of all images.
[image]

Add this configurations in mfe's project.json in order to access shared assets

[image]

To access shared image:

[image]

**4.Shared component configuartion.**

To create shared component:

```
 npx nx g component todos --project=shared-data-access-user --export
```

Import shared module in mfe’s module.ts to access the shared component

We can directly access component using selector.

[image]